# I have a bootable Ubuntu 10.10 on an old flash drive. What is the best way to update to Ubuntu 14.xx?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

I have no files I'm concerned about losing, but my flash drive is only 2GB.  Can I update through Ubuntu itself, or do I need to go through Windows?  Thanks!

Comment: personally, I'd format the flash drive and use unetbootin (or whatever is fashionable these days) to rebuild the os from scratch. 10.10 to 14.10 is just too big a jump for a dist-upgrade.

Comment: If you don't have any files on it that you are concerned about losing, is there any particular reason why you'd want to upgrade rather than just reinstall? You'd probably end up with a cleaner system if you simply reformat and reinstall a recent version, than if you try to incrementally upgrade.

Comment: @FrankThomas IIRC, Ubuntu supports going from one version to the next version, or the next version of the same type. So a non-LTS to the next version (LTS or non-LTS), or LTS to the next non-LTS or LTS version. For a larger jump, you need to upgrade in steps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm not too familiar with Ubuntu yet, so I wasnt certain if there was a suggested option, or a markedly easier option.

Comment: indeed, and neither 10.10 and 14.10 are LTS releases, and both LTS 12.04 and 14.04 lie between them, so I agree it seems to be much more of a pain to upgrade than rebuild. Personally, I've never had a dist-upgrade go right, but I've been off ubuntu since Unity anyway, so perhaps its gotten better.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicate, you should reinstall from a fresh install image, though I see no reason to use 14.10 rather than the latest 15.04.

You can down-load a new installation image by running your existing install drive in "try" mode, but it is probably easier to use a currently installed system, whether Ubuntu or Windows.

The bad news is that my 14.10 install drive is 2.3GB, and I can't imagine 15.04 is smaller, so you'll have to invest a few pence in purchasing a larger drive (or SD card, if you have a reader).

Answer (score 1):

You may consider upgrading to a newer USB 3.0 drive.  They're fairly inexpensive, and your issue won't be a problem.